# Ajax/jQuery: Same Origin Policy

Tags: ajax, firefox, jquery, security

I want to know the below pairs consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy?

`https://myserver.com/` **<-->** `https://myserver.com:443/`

Is it considered a cross domain?

My problem occurrs when client-side jQuery.ajax request to `https://myserver.com/one.action`

Then server-side `one.action` response *302* with a http header *Location* redirect to `https://myserver.com:443/two.action`

I am using jQuery 1.3.2 while MSIE6.0 treats these pairs save but Firefox dropped my connection, client-side jQuery.ajax just respond me with status = 0 and textStatus = error:

- Firefox does not request to `two.action`, error instead.
- MSIE could complete the response from `two.action` and finish the success callback.

Is it because the originating location was `https://myserver.com/` but not  `https://myserver.com:433/`? Firefox problem?

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 6.0 is not praised for its security features.  While the same protocol and same port *should* be considered the same origin, Firefox may simply decide to err on the side of safety and not trust it.